# Styled Component Not Working for background color

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styled-components

So I know this is super basic question but I cannot get back-ground or other styles to apply to my page when rendering despite my other props showing up:

**AppStyles.js**

```
import styled from 'styled-components'

const StyledContainer = styled.div`
    className = ${(props)=>props.className}
    id = ${(props)=>props.id}
    background-color: grey;
`
export {
    StyledContainer
}
```

**App.js**

```
import { StyledContainer } from './AppStyles'
import { useId } from 'react-aria'
import { isMobile } from 'react-device-detect';

function App() {

  const id = useId()
  const appClassName = isMobile ? 'container-Mobile' : 'container-Desktop'

  return (
    <StyledContainer id={id} className={appClassName}>
        <>
            testing
        </>
    </StyledContainer>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Seems to not work across a few of my local set ups, pretty weird.

Answer (score 0):

The main issue is that you don't set the attributes in the same way you set your styles. Do a refactor to make it look like this.

```js
const StyledContainer = styled.div.attrs(props => ({
  className: props.className;
  id: props.id';
}))`
  background-color: grey;
`;
```

It is also good to include the semi-colons after each property so that styled-components know what each property is. If you look at the inspect I imagine you will see only className was being added and the rest wern't